# The argument type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<news_item>>'

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, future

in code i have stored the result of an api that co-operates with another api to give result.
im getting the desired result but when i try to store that result in a list called **newsitem** im getting this error....
**news_item** is the model class of json data.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
     var stories = [news_item];
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       getNewsList();
     }
   
     getNewsList() async {
       final newsList = await getHotNewsIds()
           .then((ids) => ids.take(15).map((id) async => await getNewsItem(id)));
       print(newsList);
       List<news_item> newsitem = await Future.wait(newsList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error.

Can you try to change

```dart
final newsList = ...
```

to

```dart
final List<Future<news_item>> newsList = ...
```

What does it shows you then?

Sorry for using answer for that I have not enough reputation to comment

Edit: you could also try to use the map function as follow:

```dart
.map<Future<news_item>>(...
```

Somewhere along the line dart looses the ability to calculate the desired type, but its hard to tell without the definitions of the functions your are using (e.g. getNewsItem()) where this occurs.

Comment: iOSonntag thankyou very much it solved after using your map function. Can you kindly explain to me what went wrong there so that i can be carefull in future.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but guess using this anonymous function `(id) async => await getNewsItem(id)` doesn't explicitly tells dart its type. So dart is just recognizing the async keyword but not going any further thus leading dart in thinking the return type of that anonymous function is `Future<dynamic>` using the <> operand on the map function informs the map function which type to expect and thus the dart compiler can recognize the correct type. But as said im not 100% sure about this. If my answer solved your problem it would be helpful for me to accept the correct answer